# Performing a task every x time

Tags: java

I'm trying to perform a task every 5 minute.
The task need to start from: xx:00, xx:05, xx:10, xx:15 and so on so if the time is xx:37 the task will start in xx:40.

I'm used the following code to do that:

```
    Date d1 = new Date();
    d1.setMinutes(d1.getMinutes() + 5 - d1.getMinutes()%5);
    d1.setSeconds(0);
    this.timer.schedule(new Send(), d1, TEN_MINUTES/2);
```

Send looks like that:

```
class Send extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        if(SomeCondition)
                    {
                            Timestamp ts1 = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
                            SendToDB(ts1);
                    }
    }
}
```

So the result should be records that if you % the minutes the result would be 0.
But the records time I have is:

*05:35:00
*07:44:40
*07:54:40
*09:05:31
*09:50:00

As you can see the first task start perfectly but then something went wrong.

My guess is that the task calculateds the 5 minute jump after the previous task is finished so the task run time effects, but it's just a guess.

Comment: If you want to run at specific minutes of each hour you should take a look at Quartz Scheduler http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: "if you % the minutes the result would be 0" this is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time a task takes to execute will delay the schedule. From [the docs for `schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29):

> If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well.

You will be better off using [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29).

Alternatively, you might try using a simple `Thread` with a loop to repeatedly perform the task. The last step in the loop can be to sleep the necessary time until you want to start the task again. Assuming that no one iteration of the loop takes five minutes, this will eliminate cumulative delays.

```
public void run() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (shouldRun()) {
        doTask();
        long next = start + FIVE_MINUTES;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(next - System.currentTimeMillis());
            start = next;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            . . .
        }
    }
}
```

This will start each iteration at the next five-minute interval and will not accumulate delays due to the running time of `doTask()` or any system delays. I haven't looked at the sources, but I suspect that this is close to what's in `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Comment: A tiny question, the thread will sleep after he perform the task so if I start at xx:00 and the task takes 1 minute and he sleeps for 5 minutes the next task will be generated in xx:06

Comment: @ImriPersiado - Look carefully at how the sleep period is calculated. If the task takes one minute,  the loop iteration will then sleep for four minutes, not five.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a [Task scheduler](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/) or simply a sleep command in a loop which lets the thread sleep for 5 minutes then continue.

An alternative would be to use a [Timer class](http://www.shanison.com/2010/05/18/how-to-use-java-timer-class/)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make use of [ScheduleExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) which is a more modern approach than using a `Timer` and would allow for having multiple worker threads in case there are many tasks being scheduled.